# in eclipse i'm trying to work boxbug, however, it keeps telling me that the public void act is overriding info.gridworld.actor.Bug

Tags: java, gridworld

this is the code i am trying to use (on a mac):

```
import info.gridworld.actor.Bug;
/**
* A <code>BoxBug</code> traces out a square "box" of a given size. <br />
* The implementation of this class is testable on the AP CS A and AB exams.
*/
public class BoxBug extends Bug
{
private int steps;
private int sideLength;

 /**
 * Constructs a box bug that traces a square of a given side length
 * @param length the side length
 */
public BoxBug(int length)
{
    steps = 0;
    sideLength = length;
}

/**
 * Moves to the next location of the square.
 */

public void act()
{


    if (steps < sideLength && canMove())
    {
        move();
        steps++;
    }
    else
    {
        turn();
        turn();
        steps = 0;
    }
}
}
```

and it keeps telling me that it can't find the "attached source" when i click on the error triangle on the side. i'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the method is declared as final on the Bug superclass.

Java documentation for final methods say the following:

> You can declare some or all of a class's methods final. You use the
>   final keyword in a method declaration to indicate that the method
>   cannot be overridden by subclasses

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html

Comment: Marking methods as final is not in the AP Java subset, so that probably isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

I literally copied and pasted the code into Eclipse and it works fine. Check if your method has the same returns as the Bug class. And for the record, *none* of the GridWorld code is final. It is meant to be changed.